# How to copy and move a file one directory up?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file that I just want to copy and move into its parent directory. So far I have

```
foreach my $file (@DIR) {

    $file =~ s:.*/([^/]+):$1:;
    my $testfile = '';
    copy ($file, $testfile);

    move ($testfile, "../*");
    $file = $testfile;
}
```

Comment: maybe you need to escape the `/`.  Like so: `.*\/([^\/]+)`

Comment: I can't see any reason to quote the `/` - it isn't the delimiter

Answer (score 2):

Your `$testfile` must not be the empty string.  You can just use [copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html); you don't need `move`.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Copy qw(copy);

my $file = 'foo.txt';
my $testfile = "../$file.copy";
copy($file, $testfile);
```

It's not clear to my why you use the substitution, but it looks like you should use
[File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) `basename`.

UPDATE: Now I think I know what you want.  This will copy the file `/tmp/z/foo.txt` to the directory above: `/tmp/foo.txt`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Copy qw(copy);
use File::Basename qw(basename dirname);

my $file = '/tmp/z/foo.txt';
my $dir = dirname(dirname($file));
my $testfile = "$dir/" . basename($file);
copy($file, $testfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use system calls in perl, so you can do the following:

```
system("cp file ../");
```

Some links for examples and information:

http://perlmaven.com/running-external-programs-from-perl
http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~scheftic/PMC/UseScripts/Perl/system.html

Comment: That isn't a very portable approach.

Comment: He didn't really specify, he just said he wanted to move a file. If the post doesn't benefit the OP hopefully it would help someone else out.

Comment: I'd like to copy and move it through the script if possible since I need to use that file later.

Comment: [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) does the same thing without having to worry about 1) the command to run (`cp` on Linux, `copy` on Windows) 2) path separators 3) different return values on different OS's 4) argument quoting ...and so on. In general, I avoid using `system` for things that can be done easily in pure Perl.

Comment: You're right, it looks like a better approach.  toolic's answer seems to cover this, so user2785326 use toolic's and ThisSuitIsBlackNot's approach.